# Insert Into Two SQL Tables From XML Maintaining Relationship

Tags: sql, xml

I am looking to insert records from xml into two different tables.
For example

```
<Root>
    <A>
        <AValue>value</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>2</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
    <A>
        <AValue>value</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>3</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
</Root>
```

Would insert a record into table A
Assuming the identity is starting at 1

```
AID  AValue
1    value
2    value
```

also insert a record into table B

```
BID AID  BValue
1   1    2
2   2    3
```

I have this

```
DECLARE @idoc INT
DECLARE @doc NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @doc = '
<Root>
    <A>
        <AValue>value</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>2</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
     <A>
        <AValue>value</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>3</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
</Root>
'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

CREATE TABLE #A
    (
      AID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      AValue varchar(100)
    )

INSERT  INTO #A
        SELECT  *
        FROM    OPENXML (@idoc, '/Root/A',2)
                WITH (AValue varchar(100)
                      )  

CREATE TABLE #B
    (
      BID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      AID INT ,
      BValue INT
    )

INSERT  INTO #B
        SELECT  *
        FROM    OPENXML (@idoc, '/Root/A/Children/B',2)
                WITH (
                AID INT,
                BValue INT
                      )

SELECT  *
FROM    #A
SELECT  *
FROM    #B

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain correlation, which the below shows you how to do. I also made it more robust by adding quite a few bits of flexibility.

```
DECLARE @A table
    (
-- start with non-1, to show the solution is not dependent on starting at 1
      AID INT IDENTITY(14, 1) ,
      AValue varchar(100)
    )
DECLARE @B TABLE
    (
      BID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      AID INT ,
      BValue INT
    )

DECLARE @xml XML

-- allow for duplicate values on A.AValue
-- allow for multiple B nodes
-- allow for A nodes without B children
SET @xml = '
<Root>
    <A>
        <AValue>value2</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>2</BValue>
            </B>
            <B>
                <BValue>4</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
     <A>
        <AValue>value1</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>3</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
     <A>
        <AValue>value1</AValue>
        <Children>
            <B>
                <BValue>9</BValue>
            </B>
        </Children>
    </A>
     <A>
        <AValue>valueX</AValue>
    </A>
</Root>
'

-- dump the data into a temp table for correlating A and B entries
-- since an A can have multiple B children, ARow identifies which A it really is,
--    multiple A records can have the same AValue

declare @tmp table (ARow int, avalue varchar(100), bvalue int)
INSERT @tmp (ARow, avalue, bvalue)
SELECT X.N, X.C.value('A[1]/AValue[1]','varchar(100)'), Y.V
FROM (
    SELECT T.C.query('.') C, row_number() over (order by C) N
    FROM @xml.nodes('//A') T(C)) X
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT T2.C2.value('.','int') V
    FROM X.C.nodes('A[1]/Children/B/BValue') T2(C2)) Y

-- uncomment next line to see what has gone into @tmp
-- select * from @tmp

insert @A
select AValue
from (
    select distinct ARow, AValue
    from @tmp) X
order by ARow -- order by is important to maintain correlation

-- get the last identity generated to correlate AID in B
declare @lastid int
SET @lastid = scope_identity()

-- Max(ARow) is how many A records were entered, add back ARow to get
-- the ID generated for the A record

insert @B (AID, BValue)
select @lastid-M.M+ARow, BValue
from @tmp, (select max(ARow) M from @tmp) M
where BValue is not null
order by ARow

-- check results
select * from @A
select * from @B
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedure `sp_xml_preparedocument` is a bit old, and associated with memory leaks. It's better to avoid it if you can.

Here's a way to grab the data you seek using the newer [`xml` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
declare @doc xml
SET @doc = '...yourxml...'

create table #A (AID int, AValue varchar(50))
create table #B (BID int identity(1,1), AID int, BValue int)
create table #C (AID int, AValue varchar(50), BValue int)

insert  #C
select  *
from    (
        select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by 
                    b.value('AValue[1]', 'varchar(50)')) as aid
        ,       b.value('AValue[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        ,       g.h
        from    @doc.nodes('/Root/A') a(b)
        cross apply
                (
                select  f.value('BValue[1]', 'int')
                from    b.nodes('Children/B') e(f)
                ) g(h)
        ) b(aid, avalue, bvalue)

insert #A select distinct AID, AValue from #C
insert #B (AID, BValue) select AID, BValue from #C
```

As you can see, XML support in SQL Server is fairly convoluted.  If possible, parse the XML client-side.

Comment: This is using AValue.  I am looking to use the Primary Key that will get created from inserting the A record.

Comment: +1. good advice about sp_xml_preparedocument and memory leaks.

Comment: What if AValue is not unique?  Do I need to somehow loop through each row of nodetype A?

Comment: @Thx: In that case I think you'll need a temporary table, like `#C`.  Answer edited.

Comment: For the record, this creates multiple a records when it has multiple children, and does not allow for no children