# How often should connection be closed/opened?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am writing into two tables on SQL server row by row from C#.

My C# app is passing parameters into 2 stored procedures which are each inserting rows into tables.

Each time I call a stored procedure I open and then close the connection.

I need to write about 100m rows into the database.

Should I be closing and opening the connection every time I call the stored procedure?

Here is an example what I am doing:

```
public static void Insert_TestResults(TestResults testresults)
        {
            try
            {
                DbConnection cn = GetConnection2();
                cn.Open();

                // stored procedure
                DbCommand cmd = GetStoredProcCommand(cn, "Insert_TestResults");
                DbParameter param;

                param = CreateInParameter("TestName", DbType.String);
                param.Value = testresults.TestName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);


                if (testresults.Result != -9999999999M)
                {
                    param = CreateInParameter("Result", DbType.Decimal);
                    param.Value = testresults.Result;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }


                param = CreateInParameter("NonNumericResult", DbType.String);
                param.Value = testresults.NonNumericResult;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = CreateInParameter("QuickLabDumpID", DbType.Int32);
                param.Value = testresults.QuickLabDumpID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                // execute
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    cn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }

        }
```

Here is the stored procedure on the server:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Insert_TestResults]    Script Date: 12/26/2011 10:45:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_TestResults]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @TestName varchar (500),
    @Result decimal (18,4)=null,
    @NonNumericResult varchar (50)=null, 
    @QuickLabDumpid int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [SalesDWH].[dbo].[TestResults]
           ([TestName]
           ,[Result]
           ,nonnumericresult
           ,[QuickLabDumpid])
     VALUES
           (@TestName,@Result,@nonnumericresult,@QuickLabDumpID)


END
```

For about 100m rows it will take like 3 days. This seems too slow for me. What can I do to speed this up? What are the standards on opening/closing connection so many times?

Comment: use connection pooling , works best for large applications particularly server side.

Comment: If the test results are going to be collected on the whole and inserted to the database at the end just in one go, why trigger a parallel processing system at the end. parallel insert it into the table in say 10 or 20 batches. If and only if your records are aggregated and going to be stored only at the end.

refer : http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx

Comment: Just following up here... did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2008 you could send multiple records at once through a table-valued parameter:

```sql
create type testResultUpload as table
(
    TestName varchar(500),
    Result decimal(18,4) null,
    NonNumericResult varchar(50) null, 
    QuickLabDumpid int
)
```

Then you could build up a DataTable on the client side and pass it to sql as one chunk. Though, you may want to do a thousand at a time to start off with.

You'd have to ammend your stored procedure to deal with an input record set, starting with the parameter definition

```sql
alter proc Insert_TestResult
(
    @testResultUpload testResultUpload readonly -- tvp must be readonly
)
as begin       

    -- This is short and sweet for demonstrative purposes
    -- but you should explicitly list your columns
    insert [SalesDWH].[dbo].[TestResults] 
    select
     *
    from @testResultImport

end
```

Then on your client side:

```c
// create your datatable in the form of the newly created sql type
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("TestName", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("NonNumericResult", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("QuickLabDumpid", typeof(String));

// add your rows here (maybe do it in steps of a thousand
// 100 Million over the pipe at once is ill-advised)
// call the following code to hit sql

using (var cnx = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand {
    Connection = cnx,
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    CommandText = "dbo.Insert_TestResults",
    Parameters = {
        new SqlParameter {
            ParameterName = "@testResultUpload",
            Value = dt,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured // make sure to specify structured
        }
    }
})
{
    cnx.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: this is amazing. i will try it. what is the purpose of defining a column as nullable? would it not work if it were not nullable and i did not set a value to it?

Comment: I would not recommend inserting all 100M rows at once, without benchmarking alternatives. It is usually faster to load in batches, like 10K - 100K per batch. Depending on your constraints/triggers/etc., it might or might not make sense to load in parallel from several threads - it usually dose make sense for me.

Comment: @antisanity i do not see where we are actually passing the DT into the db?

Comment: @SurjitSamra  i do not see where we are actually passing the DT into the db?

Comment: @antisanity can you please add code on how i would connect/close connection and execute thanks!

Comment: @antisanity i was not able to declare this dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(Nullable<Decimal>)); - get an error that it cannot be nullable

Comment: @antisanity doesnt it allow null by default?

Answer (score 17):

One more option for you. The .NET Framework has had the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class since 2.0. The main thing you have to get right is making sure the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) schema matches your table. In your test case, something like this:

```
private void _initDataTable() {
  dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()  {
    DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), 
    ColumnName = "TestName"
  });
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()  {
    DataType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal"), 
    ColumnName = "Result"
  });
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()  {
    DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"), 
    ColumnName = "NonNumericResult"
  });
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()  {
    DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32"), 
    ColumnName = "QuickLabDumpid"
  });
}
```

The data access code looks something like this:

```
private void _insertData() {
  using (var c = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
    c.Open();
    using (var trans = c.BeginTransaction()) {
      try {
        using (var bc = new SqlBulkCopy(
          c, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, trans))
        {
          bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Insert_TestResults";
          bc.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        trans.Commit();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        trans.Rollback();
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tested with 10 millions records like this:

```
private void _fillDataTable() {
  int batchToInsert = 1000000;
  int numberOfTimes = 10;
  int recordCounter = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < batchToInsert; j++) {
      var row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = string.Format("TestName{0}", recordCounter);
      row[1] = (decimal) i;
      row[2] = string.Format("NonNumericResult{0}", recordCounter);
      row[3] = i;
      dt.Rows.Add(row);
      recordCounter += 1;
    }
    _insertData();
    dt.Clear();
  }
}
```

It took a little over two and a half minutes on my dev machine. You'll probably want to experiment with how many records to batch at a time. (not 1 million like the above test case) And obviously you're putting in over 10 times that amount of data into the table (guessing your live data will be larger on top of that), but I very much doubt this method will take 3 days :)

Good luck with whatever method you decide on.

**EDIT**:
If it's not apparent, I forgot to mention - since you're specifying the table name when setting the `DestinationTableName` property, that's all you need - no stored procedure or any other SQL statements.

Comment: @antisanity - thanks! +1 for your answer, which is another very good option. @I__ - never used a reflection tool to see exactly what `SqlBulkCopy` is doing, but here's some simple [comparisons with table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to help you decide on which method is best for your environment.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to open a connection for each request. You can open it once at the beginning and close it when you're done. However, with connection pooling enabled (as it is by default), opening and closing a connection is not an expensive process.

Your procedure is slow mostly because:

1. Each inserted row is in a separate single transaction
2. A separate DB round-trip for each row

The fix for the first is to group your inserts into transactions -- maybe 1000 rows per transaction or something like that.

The fix for the second is to either use command batching (send multiple commands at a time, separated by semicolons), or table valued parameters. TVP are also nice because an `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM` command executes as a single transaction.

Achievable insert speed is also limited by the speed of your log disk. Make sure the DB log is on a disk that's separate from the DB data. Ensuring that the log is de-fragmented and pre-grown to the size you need will also help.

Using `SqlBulkCopy` is another option, which can also help minimize the load on your DB log, depending on how it's configured.

In addition, if you're inserting 100M rows at the same time, you might consider dropping any indexes on the table before you start, and re-adding them once you're done. Otherwise, if you don't insert rows in the order of a clustered index, it will become fragmented very quickly, and for nonclustered indexes, you are basically doing an insert into an additional table for each insert into the main table -- on top of the fragmentation problem.

Comment: +1 - the information on temporarily dropping indexes is great advice.

Answer (score 2):

no need to close and reopen between each sp execution. In addition you may be able to decrease overall execution time by breaking the work into chunks and executing each chunk on a separate thread, so instead of 100m sequential calls, 10 threads concurrently making 10m calls each for example; one connection per thread: open, execute loop, close.

Comment: this is an awesome answer. can you please show me how i can do this multithreaded? i have ever done this

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx use parallel processing. Batch your 100m into 10m records each and process it parallely.

Comment: i understand but i do not know how to do parallel processing :)

Comment: only on phone ATM so cant put code together.  Look at System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem.  Will edit answer with code when at a PC.

Comment: you could use this technique in conjunction with that suggested by antisanity for further overall decrease

Answer (score 1):

If it is multiuser then close connection once you finsihed with them , If single user then you can keep it open for the life time of application :)

Comment: @UweKeim what are your doubts ?

Comment: Show me some references to prove your assumption. My experience tells me quite the opposite of what you write. To quote [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx): "...To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block...".

Comment: using is a standard way to clean way not to just for conenctions. You can always close/ clean up your connection manually. So if it is single user application and as OP's problem looks like migration of data then opening/closing connection is where I will like to save time.

Comment: and you will rarely have multiuser application where every user want to transfer 100m records over 3 days :) and I also some time write data migration applicaiotns :) so my Answer is from my experience of writing data migration applications and doing it from last 15 years ;)

Answer (score 1):

why not use the connections with Idisposable. In that case, you need not actually close but it will automatically go back to the connection pool. please refer this, you will understand more of what I mean. If you are having multi-threaded applications, use this way. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: you are saying just do using{connection etc....} ? in this case i would not need to explicitly close it right?

Comment: for server applications which will have large querying work should be using connection pooling for best results ! using keyword does the best work while it may look simple. Maintains the connection pool of whatever size you are mentioning it to be and disposes the connection, clears the pool and assures no db connection leaks ! I mean that's all I would ask for in a server regarding database.

Comment: Yes . you need not explicitly close. It manages the connection perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use same connectionstring on every call to `GetConnection2`, physical connection to SQL Server is *not* opened/closed every time - .NET keeps your connection open and reuse. It still causes some performance loss, but not as big as reconnecting to database.

Comment: you don't need to use the same connection string as long as you keep credentials and database. (i.e. parameter order, space etc does not affect pooling)

Comment: Try sending your rows in bulk, not *RBAR* (one-by-one). If you can, modify or create SP accepting batches of ~1k rows (e.g. serialized as XML or any other format easily parsable by SQL Server). That should reduce both workload and time needed for roundtrips to/from server.

Comment: @MagnatLU great idea. i will look into it right now. cam you please give me an example of how i would do bulk insert?

Comment: @adrianm: you also have to keep same application name in CS. I've learned that hard way when I've tried to place some context-specific data each time.

Comment: @I__: use `INSERT INTO TestResults SELECT ... FROM @xml`, there are some samples on SO, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697116

Comment: @I__: also, check BULK INSERT (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) - it might get you best results if you have data in flat file.

Answer (score 1):

The connections are cached so reopening them is cheap. Do what creates the most maintainable code.

Comment: what can i do to speed up the inserting process? do you think that 100m for 3 days is ok?

Comment: @I__: use BULK INSERT. i.e. export all data to a file and insert all rows in one go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) , nomally set on web.config, so that every time you open and close connection won't be actually opened and closed but picked from the pool. Also use `using` to make sure that you connection are properly disposed.

Comment: thank you! can you give me an example of how i would run multiple stored procedures with a data layer AND not open/close connection each time?

Comment: Connection pooling is based on connection string, as long as you use same connection string connections will be reused. You do't have to do anything special on your code but cahnge configurations of your connection string on config file

Answer (score 1):

SQL has been conceived and optimized to work on sets of records. If you work procedurally by using loops, SQL will perform badly.

I do not know if that is applicable in your case, but try using the INSERT-INTO-SELECT-FROM statement instead.

It is a good practice to close the connection, if you do not know how long it will take, until you execute the next command, however if a bunch of commands are executed in a loop, I would not close and reopen the connection each time.

Comment: If you copy records from one table into another then you would do something like: `INSERT INTO target (a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM source WHERE some condition`. You can also join tables in the select part, as in normal select statements.